# How to check the bluetooth is ON/OFF of other devices in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am working on an android app and I want to know that How i can check the status of bluetooth of other devices who are connected with my device?

When a device is connected with my device via Bluetooth then its name is saved in my phone. now how i can check the Bluetooth status of that paired devices in my app?

Comment: If a device is connected via Bluetooth, how can it's Bluetooth be deactivated at the same time?

Comment: i mean paired device. When paired device is deactivated then we will still have it in our list but it will not be connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you the following solution:

You read some data to be sended to your application, do that once at every 1 second or more (I recommend using timertask).

And another important thing for your application:
The `InputStream` and `Outputstream` objects are final so I really don't think you can reconnect to desired device without restarting application.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29) to get the list of paired devices.

You could then attempt a connection to see if the other device is available.